# Using APOC for Synchronize MonggoDB and Neo4j

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I would to have polygot persistence by having data in MongoDB and Neo4j.

As per the documentation, mongo-db-connector and neo4j doc manager would help to achieve polygot persistence. But it requires certain data structure. But I can't change the existing data structure in mongodb as below,

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5f4f9807957a736932df1a6e'),
    _relatedUserItemVersionId: '5f4f9805957a736932df19e4',
    _relatedToIds: [
        '5f4f9804256fadd9c907f2b5'
    ],
    _userType: 'system_connections',
    _customAttributes: {
        system: 663
    },
    _relatedFromUserItemVersion: 1,
    _relatedUserItemClass: 'Collection',
    _relatedFromId: '5f4f9804256fadd9c907f2b1',
    _relatedFromUserItemVersionId: '5f4f9805957a736932df19e4',
    _relatedUserItemDbId: '5f4f9805957a736932df19e3',
    _relatedUserItemVersion: 1
}
```

I would to store this document into nodes with relationships. `_relatedFromId` belongs to one node and each item in `_relatedToIds` will belongs to other nodes.

The relationship name would the value of `_userType` and have `_customAttributes` as relationship property.

Is it possible to achieve this using apoc, mongo-db-connector and neo4j doc manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j doc manager is one kind of implementation. A custom doc manager can be implemented for our requirements and given it to the mongo-db-connector. Below links would help

- https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Writing-Your-Own-DocManager
- https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-doc-manager/

Also the neo4j doc manager is pretty old, It can be used as reference to write our own implementation. Its simple and straight forward.